# Redirect all urls with specific DIR

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I redirect all the old urls with the DIR **whatever/event-calendar/whatever** like this:

`domain.com/2016-03-15-00-52-20/event-calendar/day.listevents/2016/06/30/116`

to:

`domain.com/index.php?option=com_jevents&view=month&layout=calendar`

Comment: Have you looked at [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)?

Comment: Ive used RewriteRule and Redirect but not RedirectMatch...

Answer (score 0):

Well learning RewriteMatch was the ticket!  Thanks.

This works for me:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /event-calendar/ /index.php?option=com_jevents&view=month&layout=calendar
```